# Template matching

Tags: matlab, template-matching, cross-correlation

I am trying to detect elevators on floor plans in MATLAB. The code I have now is not detecting elevators, it is instead just pointing at the edges of the image. I am expecting to detect all the elevators on a floor plan. Elevators are represented by a square or rectangle with an `x` inside, similar to the template image. I have attached the template, image and a result screenshot.

---

**Template image:**

[image: template image]

---

**Image:**

[image]

---

**Results:**

[image: results]

---

**Code**:

```
template= rgb2gray(imread('ele7.png'));
image = rgb2gray(imread('floorplan.jpg'));
%imshowpair(image,template,'montage')

c = normxcorr2(template,image);% perform cross-correlation
figure, surf(c), shading flat

[ypeak, xpeak] = find(c==max(c(:)));%peak of correlation

%Compute translation from max location in correlation matrix, =padding
yoffSet = ypeak-size(template,1);
xoffSet = xpeak-size(template,2);

%Display matched area
figure
hAx  = axes;
imshow(image,'Parent', hAx);
imrect(hAx, [xoffSet+1, yoffSet+1, size(template,2), size(template,1)]);
```

Comment: Is the template cut out from the floor plan image, or did you generate it separately? If the latter, does the size exactly match the size of the elevator you're looking for? The template must match the image exactly, otherwise cross correlation is not going to work.

Answer (score 0):

To check if everything runs smoothly, you should plot the correlation:

```
figure, surf(c)
```

As mention by @cris-luengo , it's easy to fail with the sizes of the image and so on. However, I've seen that you followed the tutorial on https://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/normxcorr2.html . Since both images, already black and white images (or 2-colour images), normxcorr2 works well with rgb images (with textures and objects, etc...). Thus, I think that is not a correct approach to use normxcorr2.

An approach I would consider is look for branches. Using Matlab's help and bwmorph:

```
BW = imread('circles.png');
imshow(BW);
BW1 = bwmorph(BW,'skel',Inf);
```

You first skeletonize the image, then you can use any of the functions that displayed on bwmorph's help (https://es.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwmorph.html). In this case, I'd search for branch points, i.e. crosslinks. It is as simple as:

```
BW2 = bwmorph(BW1,'branchpoints');
branchPointsPixels = find(BW2 == 1);
```

The indices of the branch points pixels, will be where it finds an X. However, it can be any rotated X (or +, ...). So you'll find more points that you desire, you would need to filter the points in order to get what you want.